# Code for windows phone 8 socket networking

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, windows-phone-8

This isn't a question. I'm just posting my code up, for if anyone wanted to find code to do basic networking stuff with Windows Phone 8.

Because WP8 doesn't support System.Net.Sockets, and the documentation online is not very straightforward, I found this to be a real pain to set up. So hopefully someone finds this useful.

I haven't set up advanced exception handling/extra stuff, just the bare basics here.
 If you want to, you can examine the [PC server](http://pastebin.com/Cq90tDMM) also. Cheers!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Networking;

namespace TSSClient
{

    class Client
    {
        StreamReader reader;
        StreamWriter writer;
        String GetIPAddress()
        {
            List<string> IpAddress = new List<string>();
            var Hosts = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames().ToList();
            foreach (var Host in Hosts)
            {
                string IP = Host.DisplayName;
                IpAddress.Add(IP);
            }
            return IpAddress.Last();
        }
        public async void ConnectLinear(StreamSocket socket, EndpointPair e)//connects, and then returns to the thread
        {
            await socket.ConnectAsync(e);
        }
        public bool Connect(String ipAddress)
        {
            const String port = "8020";
            try
            {
                String myIP = GetIPAddress();
                HostName localIP = new HostName(myIP);
                HostName remoteHost = new HostName(ipAddress);

                StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
                EndpointPair e = new EndpointPair(localIP, port, remoteHost, port);

                ConnectLinear(socket, e);

                if (socket.Information.LocalPort != port)//if there is no connection, control will pass to here, but the socket won't have been set up properly.
                    return false;

                Stream forReader = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
                Stream forWriter = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();

                reader = new StreamReader(forReader);
                writer = new StreamWriter(forWriter);
                writer.AutoFlush = true;
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public String SendMessage(String input)//gets a message, returns the response String
        {
            try
            {
                if (reader == null)
                    return "";
                writer.WriteLine(input);
                return reader.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Closing as unclear since there is no question here and it would be pointless to leave it open to "answers". Since the OP hasn't been seen since November, if anyone is so inclined to write up a problem statement and move the solution to an answer, please flag the question and we'll help you out.